# How to find OData version from metadata

Tags: rest, odata

I have access to a OData service. Now I need find the OData version of the service. There are version attributes in $metadata. But I don't know which one to pickup.

Do I need to take it from `<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0">` or `DataServiceVersion` or from **HTTP Header**

For example,

1. http://services.odata.org/v4/%28S%28cy2mvwlr34teasunjfqlhlyg%29%29/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata returns Version as 4.0 but does not contain DataServiceVersion in the response. But it has OData Version **HTTP header**
2. http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/$metadata returns Version as 1.0 and DataServiceVersion as 3.0. This does not contain OData Version HTTP header. But it has DataServiceVersion HTTP header
3. http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata returns Version as 1.0 and DataServiceVersion as 1.0. This does not contain OData Version HTTP header. But it has DataServiceVersion HTTP header

Please let me know how can I find the OData version using service metadata? Or is there any other way to find it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to OASIS standard, for each example:

1. v4 now needs to set `Version` on the [Edmx element](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406397928)

For examples 2 and 3, you'll want to read [this note about versioning](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#versioning) which states:

> The OData protocol supports a versioning scheme for enabling services to expose new features and format versions without breaking compatibility with older clients.
>
> OData requests and responses MAY be versioned according to The DataServiceVersion Header.
>
> An OData client SHOULD use the MinDataServiceVersion and MaxDataServiceVersion headers in order to specify the range of acceptable response DataServiceVersions.
>
> The service SHOULD respond with the maximum version supported by the service that is less than or equal to the specified MaxDataServiceVersion.

You'lll notice things are kind of the *wild wild west* in terms of OData implementations (a lot of *MAY*'s and *SHOULD*'s. In terms of how the examples above fit this specification:

2. v2 specifies that the `Version` must be `1.0`, but that the `DataServiceVersion` must be the version of OData protocol **required to consume the service**, and be one of `['1.0','2.0','3.0']`, [per spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/common-schema-definition-language-csdl/#csdl3.2.1).
3. This service is claiming to support OData clients v1-v3. So a client could submit a request with their own [`DataServiceVersion`](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#thedataserviceversionheader) of `1.0`, `2.0` or `3.0` and still receive a response that fits the standard for the given version.

So, depending on what service you're connecting to, you'll want to check differently. Maybe a flow like:

1. Check if `<edmx:Edmx />` version is `4.0` (you know OData v4)
2. Else, check if `<edmx:DataServices />` has a `MaxDataServiceVersion` property (you now have highest available OData version)
3. Else, check if `<edmx:DataServices />` has a `MinDataServiceVersion` property (you now have minimum supported OData version)
4. Else, check if `<edmx:DataServices />` has a `DataServiceVersion` property (you now have minimum supported OData version)

Comment: Not easy to find that :(